# How to create a calculated pivot table field from text data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I need to create a pivot table from the below data, summing up hours per name.

Some names appear only in one column, some in both of them.

For summing up the hours, I can use pivot's calculated field.

But is it possible to create a calculated field that would "sum up" - without duplicates - the names from both the `owner name` and `manager name` columns? If so, what would be the formula to use in such calculated field?

The desired result would be a pivot with `Name` and `Total hours` fields for example.

[image]

Comment: Is the NAME value unique? In other words, is there only one Mike? So the result for Mike would be 90, that for John would be 70, etc?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you say.

Comment: Do you only have two columns (the owner and the manager names) to sum? If so a SUM() + SUM() would work.

Comment: No, I will have more columns than two.

Comment: See section on [Pivot Table from Multiple Consolidation Ranges](https://www.contextures.com/xlPivot08.html).